# Weird Issue - DataSource is changing after injection to service

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, mybatis

This one is really puzzling me. I have a Spring Boot (2.1.2) app where I am managing two data sources via MyBatis and Spring. I have multiple MyBatis mappers and each one is configured to use a particular data source. The code for that configuration is below:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class MyBatisConfig {

    private static final String POSTGRES_SESSION_FACTORY = "postgresSessionFactory";
    private static final String MYSQL_SESSION_FACTORY = "mySqlDbSessionFactory";

    @Bean(name = POSTGRES_SESSION_FACTORY, destroyMethod = "")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean postgresSessionFactory(
            @Qualifier(DataSourceConfig.PRIMARY_DATA_SOURCE) final DataSource oneDataSource,
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(applicationContext.getResource("classpath:mybatis-config.xml"));
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(oneDataSource);
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;
        sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
        sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMapper(Mapper1.class);
        sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMapper(Mapper2.class);

        return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = MYSQL_SESSION_FACTORY, destroyMethod = "")
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean mySqlSessionFactory(
            @Qualifier(DataSourceConfig.SECONDARY_DATA_SOURCE) final DataSource anotherDataSource,
            ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(applicationContext.getResource("classpath:mybatis-config-sql.xml"));
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(anotherDataSource);
        final SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
        sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMapper(Mapper3.class);
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFactoryBean<Mapper1> accountMapperFactory(@Qualifier(POSTGRES_SESSION_FACTORY) final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        MapperFactoryBean<Mapper1> factoryBean = new MapperFactoryBean<>(Mapper1.class);
        factoryBean.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFactoryBean<Mapper2> domainMapperFactory(@Qualifier(POSTGRES_SESSION_FACTORY) final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        MapperFactoryBean<Mapper2> factoryBean = new MapperFactoryBean<>(Mapper2.class);
        factoryBean.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFactoryBean<Mapper3> usageMapperFactory(@Qualifier(MYSQL_SESSION_FACTORY) final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        MapperFactoryBean<Mapper3> factoryBean = new MapperFactoryBean<>(Mapper3.class);
        factoryBean.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

If I use my debugger, I can very that at the time these beans are being initialized, all of them are pointing to the correct data source. (Mapper1 and Mapper2's SqlSessionFactorys connect to the postgres datasource, Mapper3's SqlSessionFactory connects to the mysql datasource.

But strangely, when they are injected into a service, all three Mappers are connected to the postgres datasource. I am beyond confused at this point.

The service and injection are quite simple:

```
@Autowired private Mapper1 mapper1;
@Autowired private Mapper2 mapper2;
@Autowired private Mapper3 mapper3;
```

However when I call the service and stop it with the debugger, I can see that mapper3 is connected to the wrong datasource (postgres).

Any ideas? Any more information needed?

Comment: Are you positive that in both cases you are looking to the same instance of mapper3? Have you tried to set breakpoint on the datasource field change and/or setter to check when it changes?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same effects, when configuring multiple datasources with MyBatis. At runtime, all mappers were using the last defined datasource connection credentials, although during startup everything looked fine.

I could narrow the problem down to the factoryBean definition and setting the configuration. As it seems, the configuration object is shared among all datasources (as I set them here), because I set the same instance from the MyBatisProperties. During runtime the configuration is also the place where MyBatis gets the datasource from the Environment property.

The "magic" happens on `factoryBean.getObject()` and `factoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory()`. Here, the datasource is set into the configuration. When the configuration was not explicitly set, then a new default one is created. Otherwise, the configuration object is reused. Thus when initializing several factory beans with the same configuration object, then the configuration object gets every datasource injected and the last datasource remains.

This might be a bug, because as a Mybatis user I expect Mybatis to use the datasource I provide with `factoryBean.setDataSource(aDatasource)` So, when I commented out `factoryBean.setConfiguration`, then everything works as intended, but of course my configuration is not applied.

```
@Bean("sqlSessionFactoryA")
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(@Qualifier("datasourceA") DataSource aDataSource) throws Exception {
  SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.setDataSource(aDataSource);
  factoryBean.setConfigurationProperties(properties.getConfigurationProperties());
//    factoryBean.setConfiguration(properties.getConfiguration());
  return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

As a solution I set the `MyBatisProperties` to *prototype* scope, so that a new properties object with a new configuration object is created on each injection. This is necessary, beause I dont want to write a copy method and `org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration` does not provide a copy constructor.

```
@Bean
@Primary
@Scope("prototype")
public MybatisProperties myBatisProperties() {
  return new MybatisProperties();
}
```

Now I could also apply the configuration and everything worked fine.

```
org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration tmpConfiguration = properties.getConfiguration();
factoryBean.setConfiguration(tmpConfiguration);
```